# How to access UIView from the same xib using swift

Tags: ios, uiview, interface-builder, swift

Let me explain my problem here, I am working on a project in which I am having a xib file with a UIView. What I have done is, I created another UIView inside the same xib and I need to show that in my xib view in a button action using swift.

**Note : If I tend to do this via programatically it is working fine but the problem while I am doing with my xib. (testview) is a view that I have created inside the xib.**

```
 class tableClass: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var testview : UIView

    override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       println(testview)    **///// Return nil  /////**
       testview=UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200)) as UIView

       println(testview)    **///// Return nil  /////**
       self.view.bringSubviewToFront(testview)
       self.view.addSubview(testview)
     }
 }
```

Thanks in Advance. Please let me know, your answers and valuable ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the above stated problem by initializing my UIView in ViewDidLoad method. Here, is the lines I wrote on my didLoad method

```
class tableClass: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var testview : UIView = nil

override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   testview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
   self.view.addSubview(testview)
 }}
```

After doing that, I can able to change the UIView frame anywhere from the class, like below. Happy Coding..

```
testview.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
testview.frame = CGRectMake(50, 50, 50, 50)
```